# ProtoBuf-Net: Inheriting [ProtoMember] of type object[] from a parent class

Tags: inheritance, protobuf-net, protocol-buffers

The object[] mList holds whatever objects that the child collection wants it to. 
This is supposed to be a dummy wrapper class for the rest of the more specified collections of objects.

```
[ProtoInclude(98, typeof(Object1CollectionProto))]
[ProtoInclude(99, typeof(Object2CollectionProto))]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Object3CollectionProto))] 
public class ObjectCollectionProto
{
  protected ObjectType mCollectionType;
  protected object[] mList;
  public ObjectCollectionProto(){}

  [ProtoMember(1), DefaultValue(ObjectType.Base)]
  public ObjectType CollectionType //enumeration for type
  {
     get { return mCollectionType; }
     set { mCollectionType = value;}
  }

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public object[] List
  {
     get { return mList; }
     set { mList = value;}
  }
}
```

Then we have an example child class of the above dummy wrapper that is supposed to inherit the object[] of it's desired type.

```
 [ProtoContract]
public class Object1CollectionProto : ObjectCollectionProto
{
  public Object1CollectionProto()
  {
  }
}
```

How do I go about specifying the class hierarchy so that Object1CollectionProto inherits a the object[] mList as a list of Object1's that can be serialized? Object1's can be serialized in my case already. Just not the collection version of them.

Comment: `object[]` just isn't going to work. I can't think of any "good" ways of solving that, but looking at your data, I'm confused why you can't just replace `ObjectCollectionProto` with `List<SomeConcreteFoo>`...

Comment: I saw that in another post so I'll do it that way! Thank you Marc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to serialize arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510589/how-to-serialize-arrays)
This is a good way to **solve the problem**, just remake the framework to fit this way of serializing arrays.

Also with some careful thinking I made a way of serializing that **array** correctly. In my case I **NEVER** actually serialize the **PARENT** class, but rather I only serialize the **CHILDREN**.

I removed the ProtoMember attribute from the parent class array and set the array in the children, with a specific type into the CHILDREN classes.

```
public class BaseCollection{
  protected object[] mList;
  /*
   * this has a lot more properties/functions that declare how I prepare  
   * collections for serialization but are superfluous for the conversation, 
   * hence the reason for me wanting to know how to do this
  */
}

public class ChildCollection : BaseCollection{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public Child[] childCollection
  {
    get { return mList as Child[]; }
    set { mList = value; }
  }
}
```